# What should I do to handle C errors completely?

Tags: c, error-handling

When I use C programs, many of them defines their own error mechanisms. For that cases, I can follow their definition. How about C base libraries? Is it enough with only `errno`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to look at each function you call and then handle the return value or `errno` setting as appropriate. There is no general error handling (e.g. exceptions) beyond that.